# Using the Drawline function to create a "pencil stroke"

Tags: android

Ok so I'm making a game and I'm having a problem, that Is I don't have
anyway of going about this, Making a line that looks like a pencil stroke.
I start out with

```
drawLine(float startX, float startY, float stopX,float stopY, Paint paint);
```

of course
and then I I use all the stuff involved with `Paint()` and the paint
class so I set the color and the thickness in the paint...

So What I'm wondering is how do I give my paint a texture that
resembles a pencil stroke. is there a way I can make the paint look
like a repeated bitmap, what are my options with this.

Thanks, Brian

p.s. if you want more detail I can expound on it a little more like
give you the exact code that I'm using and explain more about my
game....
also here are links to the paint class and the canvas class if you
need them.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint.html

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html

Also

```
void drawBitmap(int[] colors, int offset, int stride, float x, float y, int width, int height, boolean hasAlpha, Paint paint)
```

Treat the specified array of colors as a bitmap, and draw it."
Can I use that I'm really not sure what its saying.

please even if you have a little information please reply.

Answer (score 0):

> "void drawBitmap(int[] colors, int offset, int stride, float x, float y, int width, int height, boolean hasAlpha, Paint paint) Treat the specified array of colors as a bitmap, and draw it." Can I use that I'm really not sure what its saying.

It seems you would want this version of the Canvas.drawBitmap() series of methods: `drawBitmap(Bitmap  bitmap, Rect  src, Rect  dst, Paint  paint)`.
Ideally you could make your own texture and either stretch it or tile it.. I'm not sure how to tile, but a link in the "Related" section to the right points at `TileMode.REPEAT` of class `BitmapShader`.

If your texture isn't going to have any noise ( or anything else that would distort upon stretching ) you may just want to use `Drawable.draw()` and use a 9-patch for your pencil-stroke.

Comment: So if I do this will I still use Canvas.drawline... or do I set the "rect dst" as my line cordinates.. sorry I'm a little confused in this area of android. thank you

Comment: You do not use `drawLine()`.. `Rect dst` will be your new coordinates. Say you want to make a pencil-stroke with a width of 4 with the top line starting at (0,0) going to (0,100) you would use the following: `drawBitmap( myBitmap, null, new Rect( 0,0,4,100 ), myPaint )`. If you haven't read the documentation for `Rect` it may be useful.